# Updating cloud-init on Azure Scale Set with ARM

Tags: azure, cloud-init, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template that deployes a scaleset to Azure and creates configuration files and runs a docker container via cloud-init.

All this works file and we have Azure DevOps running the template and redeploy on changes. BUT any changes to the cloud init file are not reflated until we manually reimage the servers. Is there any way to automatically (and preferably rolling) replace all the servers in the scaleset with the updated configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using the Rest API from: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/custom-data#can-i-update-custom-data-after-the-vm-has-been-created